# How can i adding more nodes in first.cc in ns3?

Tags: c++, ns-3

I've just learned about first.cc and I want to change the number of nodes in first.cc from 2 to 3 or 4 5, but changing only nodes.Create(2) ==> nodes.Create(3) causes me some errors like this

*assert failed.cond="c.GetN () ==2" , +0.00000000s -1 file=../src/point-to-point/helper/point-to-point-helper.cc, line=224
terminate called without an active exception*

So I've to add some connection between them or else? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about the tutorial at https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/? Nobody will know what `first.cc` is supposed to be. It is just a file name. Also, please do not show code and other text in images. Instead copy-paste into the question. See [ask]. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: oh yes , sorry about that , i putted it on the titles but when i kept ending with "title  does not meet quality standards?" so after changed it many times i forgot about it ,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to start by encouraging you to use gdb (or lldb) to debug the program. If you did this, you would have found that [this line in first.cc](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.35/doxygen/first_8cc_source.html#l00052) is causing the error:

```cpp
devices = pointToPoint.Install (nodes);
```

Why would this happen? Well, if we go to [the definition of the function being called](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.35/doxygen/point-to-point-helper_8cc_source.html#l00224), we find:

```cpp
NetDeviceContainer 
PointToPointHelper::Install (NodeContainer c)
{
    NS_ASSERT (c.GetN () == 2);              // line 224
    return Install (c.Get (0), c.Get (1));
}
```

Looking at this code, it is clear that the PointToPointHelper::Install(NodeContainer) imposes the constraint that the NodeContainer can only contain two Nodes. This explains how the error you encountered occurred.

But why?

It's a (good) design choice. A PointToPointChannel can only be installed between exactly two PointToPointNetDevices, not more, not less. So, the implementation imposes the constraint that the NodeContainer can only contain two Nodes.